# Solana Anchor how to define custom types with array of structs?

Tags: rust, solana

After moving my structs inside the pub mod xyz {...}, My Rust code:

```
#[state]
#[derive(Default)]
#[derive(Copy)]//index as pid
pub struct Ppool {
  pub alloc_point: u64,
}
#[state]
pub struct Counter {
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub count: u64,
    pub pool_array: [Ppool; 20],
}

impl Counter {
    pub fn new(ctx: Context<Auth>) -> Result<Self> {
        Ok(Self {
            authority: *ctx.accounts.authority.key,
            count: 0,
            pool_array: [
              Ppool {
              alloc_point: 0,
            }; 20],
        })
    }
```

My Rust program can compile, but Anchor does not run with error:

```
await program.state.rpc.new({
  accounts: {
    authority: provider.wallet.publicKey,
  },
});
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'rpc' of undefined

I know from this tutorial Basic1: https://project-serum.github.io/anchor/tutorials/tutorial-1.html#defining-a-program, it says "If you'd like to pass in your own type as an input to an instruction handler, then it must be defined in the same src/lib.rs file as the #[program] module, so that the IDL parser can pick it up.", and tutorial Basic4 about state structs...

Furthermore, if I move the Ppool struct outside of the mod, the Rust will compile, but Anchor will say "Error: User defined types not provided"... So I think the Ppool struct should stay inside the mod

but after moving my Ppool struct into the mod, my Ppool struct cannot have #[state] ... see the errors below:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound Ppool: Clone is not satisfied
--> programs/basic-4/src/lib.rs:11:14
|
11 | #[derive(Copy)]//index as pid
| ^^^^ the trait Clone is not implemented for Ppool
|
= note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound Ppool: anchor_lang::AnchorDeserialize is not satisfied
--> programs/basic-4/src/lib.rs:16:5
|
16 | #[state]
| ^^^^^^^^ the trait anchor_lang::AnchorDeserialize is not implemented for Ppool
|
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of anchor_lang::AnchorDeserialize for [Ppool; 20]
= help: see issue #48214
= help: add #![feature(trivial_bounds)] to the crate attributes to enable
= note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)

error[E0277]: the trait bound Ppool: anchor_lang::AnchorSerialize is not satisfied
--> programs/basic-4/src/lib.rs:16:5
|
16 | #[state]
| ^^^^^^^^ the trait anchor_lang::AnchorSerialize is not implemented for Ppool
|
= note: required because of the requirements on the impl of anchor_lang::AnchorSerialize for [Ppool; 20]
= help: see issue #48214
= help: add #![feature(trivial_bounds)] to the crate attributes to enable
= note: this error originates in a derive macro (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
```

What kind of macro should I add for my Ppool struct inside the mod?

Comment: Are you defining those accounts outside the program module (in the global scope)?

Comment: Hi after moving structs into the mod, Rust can compile, but Anchor says "TypeError: Cannot read property 'rpc' of undefined", how to call struct method?

Comment: So I have to move those structs into the mod, but my Ppool struct cannot have #[state] or Anchor's idl does not show any method thus rpc call failed. What kind of macro should I add for my Ppool struct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by putting arrays into an array of structs... please see Anchor repo > tests > zero-copy